# Convert slice of string to slice of pointer to string

Tags: string, pointers, for-loop, go, memory

I want to convert a slice of string into slice of pointer to string

```
values1 := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
var values2 []*string
for _, v := range values1 {
    fmt.Printf("%p | %T\n", v, v)
    values2 = append(values2, &v)
}
fmt.Println(values2)
```

> %!p(string=a) => string 
>   %!p(string=b) => string 
>   %!p(string=c) => string 
>   [0xc42000e1d0 0xc42000e1d0 0xc42000e1d0]

From my understanding, 
My variable `v` seems to be a string, not a pointer to string. 
Therefore `v` should be copied from `values1` when iterating.

Obviously I'm incorrect as `v` still have the same address `0xc42000e1d0`. 
How can `v` value change if it's not a pointer?

**For a quick solution use:**

```
values1 := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
var values2 []*string
for i, _ := range values1 {
    values2 = append(values2, &values1[i])
}
```

Comment: What's the question? The first version doesn't work because there is only one loop variable (reused in each iteration), and you append the same address in each iteration. See examples [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715882/why-do-these-two-for-loop-variations-give-me-different-behavior/44716068#44716068) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044245/golang-register-multiple-routes-using-range-for-loop-slices-map/44045012#44045012).

Comment: @icza updated with question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first version doesn't work as there is only one loop variable `v`, which has **the same address in each iteration**. The loop variable is assigned in each iteration, which changes its value but not its address, and you append this same address in each iteration.

A possible solution is what you proposed: to append the address of the proper slice element of the original slice:

```
for i := range values1 {
    values2 = append(values2, &values1[i])
}
```

This works, but note that `values2` contains addresses pointing to the backing array of `values1`, so the backing array of `values1` will be kept in memory (will not get garbage collected) until both `values1` and `values2` variables are unreachable. Also note that modifying elements of `values1` will effect `values2` indirectly, because elements of `values2` point to elements of `values1`.

Another solution is to create temporary local variables and append the addresses of those:

```
for _, v := range values1 {
    v2 := v
    values2 = append(values2, &v2)
}
```

By doing this, your `values2` slice will not keep `values1` from getting garbage collected, also modifying values in `values1` will not be reflected in `values2`, they will be independent.

See related questions about the loop variable:

[Why do these two for loop variations give me different behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715882/why-do-these-two-for-loop-variations-give-me-different-behavior/44716068#44716068)

[Golang: Register multiple routes using range for loop slices/map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044245/golang-register-multiple-routes-using-range-for-loop-slices-map/44045012#44045012)

Comment: Thanks for the tips about copying the value in a temporary variable

Answer (score 2):

The iteration values in a `for .. range` clause are assigned for each iteration.

The [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) clearly states:

> The iteration values are assigned to the respective iteration
>   variables as in an assignment statement.

This is the equivalent of doing:

```
var v string
v = string1
values[0] = &v
v = string2
values[1] = &v
etc...
```

The variable `v` still lives in the same area of memory, it's just that the contents change. So the address of `v` never changes.