# How to convert []*Cookie to []Cookie in Golang

Tags: go

I have a []*Cookie array, but how to get []Cookie array? I tried to use the * symbol but there was a syntax error.

Comment: Why do you need to do the conversion?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48459846/13860

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go does not provide an automatic conversion from slice of pointers to values to a slice of values.

Write a loop to do the conversion:

```
result := make([]Cookie, len(source))
for i := range result {
    result[i] = *source[i]
}
```