# Using Pointers in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, pointers, go, mutex

I'm struggling to understand why I have a bug in my code in one state but not the other. It's been a while since I've covered pointers, so I'm probably rusty!

Basically I have a repository structure I'm using to store an object in memory, that has a `Store` function.

```
type chartsRepository struct {
    mtx    sync.RWMutex
    charts map[ChartName]*Chart
}

func (r *chartsRepository) Store(c *Chart) error {
    r.mtx.Lock()
    defer r.mtx.Unlock()
    r.charts[c.Name] = c
    return nil
}
```

So all it does is put a RW mutex lock on and adds the pointer to a map, referenced by an identifier.

Then I've got a function that will basically loop through a slice of these objects, storing them all in the repository.

```
type service struct {
    charts Repository
}

func (svc *service) StoreCharts(arr []Chart) error {
    hasError := false
    for _, chart := range arr {
        err := svc.repo.Store(&chart)
        // ... error handling
    }
    if hasError {
        // ... Deals with the error object
        return me
    }
    return nil
}
```

The above doesn't work, it looks like everything works fine at first, but on trying to access the data later, the entries in the map all point to the same `Chart` object, despite having different keys.

If I do the following and move the pointer reference to another function, everything works as expected:

```
func (svc *service) StoreCharts(arr []Chart) error {
    // ...
    for _, chart := range arr {
        err := svc.storeChart(chart)
    }
    // ...
}

func (svc *service) storeChart(c Chart) error {
    return svc.charts.Store(&c)
}
```

I'm assuming the issue is that because the loop overwrites the reference to the `chart` in the `for` loop, the pointer reference also changes. When the pointer is generated in an independent function, that reference is never overwritten. Is that right?

I feel like I'm being stupid, but shouldn't the pointer be generated by `&chart` and that's independent of the `chart` reference? I also tried creating a new variable for the pointer `p := &chart` in the `for` loop and that didn't work either.

Should I just avoid generating pointers in loops?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This is because there is only a single loop variable `chart`, and in each iteration just a new value is assigned to it. So if you attempt to take the address of the loop variable, it will be the same in each iteration, so you will store the same pointer, and the pointed object (the loop variable) is overwritten in each iteration (and after the loop it will hold the value assigned in the last iteration).

This is mentioned in [Spec: For statements: For statements with `range` clause:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)

> The iteration variables may be declared by the "range" clause using a form of [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) (`:=`). In this case their types are set to the types of the respective iteration values and their [scope](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) is the block of the "for" statement; **they are re-used in each iteration**. If the iteration variables are declared outside the "for" statement, after execution their values will be those of the last iteration.

Your second version works, because you pass the loop variable to a function, so a copy will be made of it, and then you store the address of the copy (which is detached from the loop variable).

You can achieve the same effect without a function though: just create a local copy and use the address of that:

```
for _, chart := range arr {
    chart2 := chart
    err := svc.repo.Store(&chart2) // Address of the local var
    // ... error handling
}
```

Also note that you may also store the address of the slice elements:

```
for i := range arr {
    err := svc.repo.Store(&arr[i]) // Address of the slice element
    // ... error handling
}
```

The disadvantage of this is that since you store pointers to the slice elements, the whole backing array of the slice would have to be kept in memory for as long as you keep any of the pointers (the array cannot be garbage collected). Moreover, the pointers you store would share the same `Chart` values as the slice, so if someone would modify a chart value of the passed slice, that would effect the charts whose pointers you stored.

See related questions:

[Golang: Register multiple routes using range for loop slices/map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044245/golang-register-multiple-routes-using-range-for-loop-slices-map/44045012#44045012)

[Why do these two for loop variations give me different behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715882/why-do-these-two-for-loop-variations-give-me-different-behavior/44716068#44716068)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm not sure I understand why `p := &chart` in the loop wouldn't work though, is that a pointer to whatever `chart` is rather than a pointer to whatever `chart` was at the time? The wording on the golang tutorials suggests the pointer is 'generated' by the code `&chart`. https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

Maybe I'm better having a repository accepting the objects themselves, rather than pointers and always making copies to avoid the potential pitfalls and garbage collection issues?

Comment: @Simon If you do `p := &chart`, then you again take the address of the single loop variable and store it in a variable (of pointer type), and then you store this single pointer in each iteration. The stress is making a copy of the `chart` value, and then the address of this new variable and not the loop variable.

Comment: @Simon And there is nothing wrong making a copy of it in a local variable and taking its address. In Go it is perfectly normal to take the address of a local variable, the runtime and the garbage collector keep track of all this and the pointed object will be available for as long as you have the pointer. Go is not like C in this regard.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but I think in terms of how a repository should work with functions like `Store`, maybe it makes more sense on an business-level to make copies and keep them. Especially since this in-memory storage will be replaced by something persistent at some point. Thanks @icza, that's really helped.

Comment: https://twitter.com/jawspeak/status/1382842060487626753 is this in the form of a puzzle and https://play.golang.org/p/Xmn7OWbSnO_k demonstrates some solutions

Answer (score 6):

I faced a similar issue today and creating this simple example helped me understand the problem.

```golang
// Input array of string values
inputList := []string {"1", "2", "3"}
// instantiate empty list
outputList := make([]*string, 0)

for _, value := range inputList {
    // print memory address on each iteration
    fmt.Printf("address of %v: %v\n", value, &value)
    outputList = append(outputList, &value)
}

// show memory address of all variables
fmt.Printf("%v", outputList)
```

This printed out:

```golang
address of 1: 0xc00008e1e0
address of 2: 0xc00008e1e0
address of 3: 0xc00008e1e0
[0xc00008e1e0 0xc00008e1e0 0xc00008e1e0]
```

As you can see, the address of `value` in each iteration was always the same even though the actual value was different ("1", "2", and "3"). This is because `value` was getting reassigned.

In the end, every value in the `outputList` was pointing to the same address which is now storing the value "3".