# How to create Cron tasks by one single func with diffenent Parameters?

Tags: go

```golang
c := cron.New()
task := inittask()
for _, ta := range task {
    c.AddFunc("*/10 * * * * *", func() {getdata(ta, DBS, DBT)})
}
c.Start()
select {}
```

Not working, only the  first or the last parameter works.

Comment: Explain "not working"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Pointers in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48826460/using-pointers-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_, v := range` loop allocates one `v` variable and then **re-uses** it in each iteration.

And when you use *closures* within such a loop you are capturing that re-used variable which causes each closure to refer to the same memory address and, therefore, when the loop exits, each closure will have the data of the last iteration.

https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

```golang
c := cron.New()
task := inittask()
for _, ta := range task {
    ta := ta // copy ta
    c.AddFunc("*/10 * * * * *", func() {getdata(ta, DBS, DBT)})
}
c.Start()
select {}
```

Alternatively, you can also get around the problem this way:

```golang
c := cron.New()
task := inittask()
for i := range task {
    c.AddFunc("*/10 * * * * *", func() {getdata(task[i], DBS, DBT)})
}
c.Start()
select {}
```